# Webscraping with Python, I can't see the actual names of classes when I say inspect page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Ok so I am just learning python and I want to use web scraping. I was watching this tutorial and there the tutor has a totally different "inspect" page(or whatever it is called) than mine. So what he sees is class = "ProfileHeaderCard", and what I see is class = "css-1dbjc4n r-1iusvr4 r-16y2uox r-5f2r5o r-m611by". THE IMPORTANT PART is that BeautifulSoup library does not work when I use my version of the class name but it works when I use his version. When I say `print(soup.find('div', {"class":"css-1dbjc4n r-1iusvr4 r-16y2uox r-5f2r5o r-m611by"}))`
it returns None
What is going on lol please help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

theurl = 'https://twitter.com/1kasecorba'
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('div', {"class":"css-1dbjc4n r-1iusvr4 r-16y2uox r-5f2r5o r-m611by"}))
```

Comment: can you share a link to the page you are looking at?

Comment: Share the url to the page and your full code. It's possible that the div could be generated via script so it won't show up in the html if you only send a request.

Comment: @JosephRajchwald I added the full code above.

Comment: @osonuyi I added the link above aswell.

Comment: This might be due to the version change in the website. The tutorial video might be old and the website might have changed their code since then.  Also a lot of the websites these days load their content dynamically using JS, so whole HTML code  is not available to you by simply sending a `GET` request. Disable JS on your browser and load the page again to see the content that you'll get on a `GET` request.

Comment: @techytushar thank you so much. My first time on stackoverflow .. total success:D

Answer (score 0):

It does not find it because it is not there. Note that when you perform GET request on a page, you often don't get the same source you see when you open a page in a browser and see source there (Control + U).

I wrote a script that writes the content of source got by urllib to a text file, and no such class you are looking for is there. There's nothing wrong with the soup.find function, as you will see on the example at the last line.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

theurl = 'https://twitter.com/1kasecorba'
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'html.parser')

file = open("page_source.txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8")
file.write(str(soup))
file.close()

# works as charm
print(soup.find('button', {"class":"modal-btn modal-close modal-close-fixed js-close"}))
```

If you want to see the real source, you will need a tool like Selenium (there are probably better options, I can't give much advice on this topic).